# Basic Python - variables

Tags: python, mysql, variables

A client asked me if I could make a system around his python application.
The problem is that the name of the mysql tables are variables, for example in PHP I would do this:

```
    <?php
    $type = "facebook";
    mysql_query("SELECT uid FROM users_".$type." WHERE username='foo'");
    ?>
```

Now I am trying to achieve the same thing in python, I have this block of code:

```
    self.exeute(
        """
        SELECT uid FROM `users_FACEBOOK` WHERE `username` = 'foo'
        """
    )
```

How can I replace "FACEBOOK" by a variable? (it must be fetched using the getattr-function.
I have tried

```
    users_%(getattr(settings, 'TYPE'))
    'users_'+str(getattr(settings, 'TYPE'))
```

Both give errors..

Comment: Looks like a bogus database design but it exists and so you have to work with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FACEBOOK = <get the value>
self.execute('select uid from `users_%s` where `username`="foo"' %(FACEBOOK))
```

Comment: Althought this works, it is preferred to use format instead: `execute("SELECT * FROM `user_{suffix}`".format(suffix=FACEBOOK))`

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have:

```
TYPE = 'FACEBOOK'
```

This will give you the string with the variable name:

```
varName = 'user_' + TYPE
```

and this the value in the variable:

```
locals()[varName]
```

Take a look at the help of locals.

> locals(...)
>      locals() -> dictionary
>
> Update and return a dictionary containing the current scope's local variables.